# How to add role to a member after he/she passes member screening on Discord?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

If you have any **join-role** on a server, then the member screening won't happen. Since in the members screen section it states that if a member is given a role, it bypasses the screening.
So how can the **join-role** be given after the screening?
What event can I use and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Client#guildMemberUpdate()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate), which emits when anything about a member changes. It passes two parameters, the old member, and the new guild member. You can then check through [`GuilMember#pending`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=pending) if the member went through screening, although this is only possible on discord.js master.

```js
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  if (oldMember.pending && !newMember.pending) {
    // add the role!
  }
});
```